# Exposing alternate port of jupyter container not working

Tags: r, docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm attempting to run the jupyter container of r-noteb ook (https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/r-notebook/) on port 10000 .

Using command :

```
docker run -p 10000:10000 jupyter/r-notebook
```

This is the output :

```
Executing the command: jupyter notebook
[I 14:14:28.508 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 14:14:28.954 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 14:14:28.955 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[I 14:14:28.959 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan
[I 14:14:28.959 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 14:14:28.959 NotebookApp] http://(165e94335316 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=45a5ff037dfa5dfd8aca69ae8489b4bb814009a9b7f6abf6
[I 14:14:28.959 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 14:14:28.961 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://(165e94335316 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=45a5ff037dfa5dfd8aca69ae8489b4bb814009a9b7f6abf6
```

From output :

```
to login with a token:
            http://(165e94335316 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=45a5ff037dfa5dfd8aca69ae8489b4bb814009a9b7f6abf6
```

can see port `8888` is exposed instead of `10000`

Have I mapped the port correctly ?

Accessing `http://localhost:10000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:10000/` or `http://165e94335316:10000/` on browser returns 'page not found' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it using `docker run -p 10000:8888 jupyter/r-notebook` and access http://localhost:10000. Right side port should be `8888` because all Jupyter notebook containers are exposed on port `8888` as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/a238993ad594eeddb19c5b455bafcb345e4fe8e6/base-notebook/Dockerfile#L107).

In `-p 10000:8888`, `8888` is the port where jupyter notebook is running inside the container. `10000` is the port to which the notebook running in the container is exposed to the host machine.

**One more tip:** To access Jupyter notebook from http://localhost:8888, change `10000` to `8888`.

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/r-notebook
```